# Trying to determine if a string contains only letters in Java

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, char

My code is below:

```
} else if (words.toUpperCase().equals(words)) {
    for (int i = 0; words.length() > i; i++){
      thisLetter = words.charAt(i);
      letter = thisLetter.isLetter();
      if (!letter){
        break;
      }
    }
```

letter is a boolean, thisLetter is a Character type (not a char).
For some reason I get the following error when compiling:

```
 no suitable method found for isLetter()
method java.lang.Character.isLetter(int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method java.lang.Character.isLetter(char) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: what do you mean by words.toUpperCase().equals(words)?

Comment: Does it have to be an upper-case "J"?

Comment: The point of this code is to determine if a string is in all uppercase. That bit of code checks that, but it also returns true if there are non-letters in the word.

Comment: `thisLetter.isLetter()` is wrong.  Should be `Character.isLetter(thisLetter)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `letter = thisLetter.isLetter();`, which returns a primitive `char`.  The returned value will be auto-boxed into a `Character` by the compiler

`Character` does not have a method `isLetter()`, instead, you should try...

```
letter = Character.isLetter(thisLetter);
```

Assuming of course, that `thisLetter` is a `char`...

Consult the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) for more details

Comment: That worked, thanks! What was wrong with what I was doing though?

Comment: `Character` doesn't have a method `isLetter()`, it has a `static` method called `isLetter(char)`

Answer (score 0):

Lessee:

```
boolean containsOnly = true;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++) {
    char theChar = words.charAt(i);
    int index = "Java".indexOf(theChar);
    if (index < 0) {
       containsOnly = false;
       break;
    }
}
```